# Wireshark conversation list sides

Tags: sockets, wireshark, mac-address

When the wireshark conversation list is opened (statistics ->conversation list) Wireshark is showing a column of "packets A->B"  and a column of "packets B->A". When I'm sniffing on one side of the traffic (physically)  I can see that about half the mac addresses have traffic only on "A->B" and not on "B->A" and the other half is the other way around, which makes sense, because I sniffed on one side of the conversations.

The question is: How does wireshark decide what address to call "side A" and what address to call "side B"? It's easy to see from what I described above that it doesn't depend on which side sent more packets/sent the first packet and I find it hard to believe it is decided randomally.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the code that fills this list (`ui/gtk/conversations_table.c:1726`)](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=ui/gtk/conversations_table.c;h=7fc02e2eb031099e4f469564f44d1d5b60d810fb;hb=b16166c36abc6c63d9643defd1f2fb8ef5cf6343#l1726):

```
gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(store, &iter, G_MAXINT,
        CONV_COLUMN_SRC_ADDR, src_addr,
        CONV_COLUMN_SRC_PORT, src_port,
        CONV_COLUMN_DST_ADDR, dst_addr,
        CONV_COLUMN_DST_PORT, dst_port,
        CONV_COLUMN_PACKETS,  conv_item->tx_frames+conv_item->rx_frames,
        CONV_COLUMN_BYTES,    conv_item->tx_bytes+conv_item->rx_bytes,
        CONV_COLUMN_PKT_AB,   conv_item->tx_frames,
        CONV_COLUMN_BYTES_AB, conv_item->tx_bytes,
        CONV_COLUMN_PKT_BA,   conv_item->rx_frames,
        CONV_COLUMN_BYTES_BA, conv_item->rx_bytes,
        CONV_COLUMN_START,    start_time,
        CONV_COLUMN_DURATION, duration,
        CONV_COLUMN_BPS_AB,   tx_ptr,
        CONV_COLUMN_BPS_BA,   rx_ptr,
        CONV_INDEX_COLUMN,    idx,
        -1);
```

…we can see that internally, they don't use "Address A" and "Address B"—**it's "source" and "destination" addresses of the packet**. You can also see that "A→B" columns will show TX (i.e. transmitted, outgoing) counts while "B→A" columns show RX (i.e. received, incoming) counts.

Comment: Then how does wireshark decide an address is "address A" while the column "packets A->B" has the value 0?

Comment: I have no answer for that; I'll have to dive into the code once I catch some sleep. Reality check: did you actually see Wireshark display 0 in "Packets A→B" column?

Comment: Yes I did. I would have posted a screenshot but the capture file is in my work's LAN.

Comment: What protocols are you analyzing? As far as I can see, Bluetooth, ETH, FC, FDDI, Wi-Fi, IP4/6, IPX, JXTA, NCP, RSVP, SCTP, TCP, TR, UDP and USB all set "Packet A" to first packet's source address.

Comment: I can see it in ipv4 but it's most significantly seen in ethernet.

Comment: Read through Ethernet dissector once again to make sure, but still don't have an answer to your question. As a last ditch, what version of Wireshark are you using? Maybe the code I'm looking at is just too different from the one you're running.